# link_to post method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, link-to

how to create link_to become method post in rails?, i try to send params to controller via link to. i have route like this :

```
match '/create_session_upload_pdf_id' => "dashboard#create_session_upload_pdf_id", :as => "create_session_upload_pdf_id",  :via => [ :post ]
```

and i have link_to in view like this :

```
<%= link_to image_tag('image.png', :alt => 'click me', :id => 'test'), create_session_upload_pdf_id_path(bill: @bill), method: :post %>
```

why if i click link_to, not send post but become to get?
please tell me if i'm wrong?

Comment: check page source data-method is post or not you cna use button_to helper also http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to

Comment: Ensure that you have `//= require jquery_ujs` in your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`